Movie where three people caught in dire situation have to single out one person to get rid of
I forget the title to this movie - the scene I recall is as follows:
(I think this occurred towards the ending / near the end of the movie)
There are three people, two are identical [twins?] and one is some sort of evil [clone?] and the other is the original good person. The third person has a hose or some type of spraying object.
The third person has to decide which of the two identical people to get rid of/kill -- and I think the final trump was probably some sort of question only the original was supposed to know?
I think the two are identical may have been female/actresses (although I'm not entirely sure). All three were white characters and the movie was definitely in English. The movie may be at least a decade (possibly two) or more old, and I'd say it might have been a more popular title at the time? The three were younger in age (e.g. closer towards children/young adult as opposed to older-grandparents).
I feel like the scene has possibly been adapted in later content (sitcoms? interviews?) as a very short sketch/joke to play off of the original scene/movie I described too.
Any ideas?

Thanks for the detailed question, but 'Spot the Impostor' scenes are quite common in sci-fi. The hose thing is a bit different, though (but currently doesn't ring a bell). Do you remember anything else about the plot?

I wish I did :/ I think I may have found a shot of the picture or even the title itself in the past, but have since forgot. I feel if I make anymore guesses I might start describing bogus details - e.g. I want to say they were outside and maybe the scene was next to a well (how one twin meets their demise) - but I don't think I can be even half certain this actually happened for the shot I'm describing.

I think you're looking for an episode of Are you afraid of the dark called "Tale of the Chameleons".
It has the twins from the show Sister Sister. On the most part it matches very well to your question.
At the end of the episode the 3 females 'all quite young' are stood by a Well. One of the girls has to decide which is the real person and uses a hose to spray the evil one. Once she turns back into a Chameleon she is thrown down a Well.
Full Episode on Youtube:




Thanks for the reply tohood87, do you know of any earlier-dated scenarios that took place (and which this scene may be based / adapted from?) Your response fits almost exactly what I recall except for the actresses and time of day - my memory says it took place at/after dusk but again I could be mistaken and would just want to see similar (if any) scenes/shots to this to be more sure. movies.stackexchange.com has really helpful people :)

@NickBell - the trouble is it's a very popular trope that's been used for many years. The part about the Hose and Well was too much of a good fit not to post an answer. Sorry it wasn't the one though & hope you find it at some point. If you remember anything else I recommend adding more detail, was water sprayed from the hose? Which isn't very lethal unless your the witch from Wizard of Oz :) Or was it something like liquid nitrogen? Or did the pressure of the hose/ spray force the person to fall down the Well?

tohood87, going through watching episodes of Are You Afraid of the Dark? Will see if this is what I recollect :)
